# Import Java library into Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I would like to create a test project in Eclipse.  My goal is to add AND USE all the class files from the library. How would I do that ? It's this particular library https://github.com/twitter/hbc. I know how to import class files in XCode (Mac/iOS), but whenever I worked with Eclipse it has always been the import which produced the most problems and shied me away. I have tried to drop the master folder into a newly created java-project, however I am not quite sure how to import them (especially because of the folder structure of the library).

Comment: Use Maven. It'll make your life a lot easier...

Comment: @ppeterka66 what's Maven ?

Comment: [I don't think Google is down...](http://maven.apache.org/) [The wiki is also full of info...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven)

Comment: "Apache Maven is a software project management and comprehension tool." It can help you manage project dependencies (external Java libraries), and more. http://maven.apache.org/

Comment: or you can use IvyDE ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right click on your project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path...
On Tab Libraries -> Add JARs... -> select your library .jar file. (must be visible within your workspace, best added to a lib-folder within your project).

otherwise install the Maven Integration for Eclipse plugin and make your project a maven managed project: Help -> Eclipse Marketplace... -> search m2e -> scroll down -> install.

Maven is a Build tool that helps your managing your dependencies. You add your dependency to a library as a short xml text in the pom.xml file and maven downloads and links the library to your project automatically. Read more about it in the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).